# How to wake up the app with Eddystone in Android

Tags: android, beacon, wakeup

I want to wake up my app with Eddystone, however nothing happened when my phone get close to the signal of Eddystone. I did it with Android Beacon library. And it is as blew:

```
    `
onCreate(){
    mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    // Detect the main Eddystone-UID frame:
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(50);
    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(50);
    mBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(50);
    mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(50);
    mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(50);
    mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(50);
    mBeaconManager.applySettings();
    mBeaconManager.bind(this);
```

}`

Android.xml:

```
<application 
    android:name="com.example.MyApplicationName"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- Note:  the singleInstance below is important to keep two copies of your activity from getting launched on automatic startup -->
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"  
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Is there anyone did it before, please help me with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to wake up an app with Eddystone-UID using the Android Beacon Library.  It works the same way as with AltBeacon or iBeacon.

The easiest way to get this to happen is to start with the reference app here:

https://github.com/altbeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

The only modification you need to make is to add the beacon parser for Eddystone-UID:

```
mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
        setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
```

Looking at the code in the question, setting the scan periods to 50 is going to be a problem, as 50ms is not long enough to reliably detect a beacon.  I would remove these custom scan period configurations and use the defaults.

A few tips:

1. Make sure you can detect beacons in the foreground before trying to make your app work in the background.
2. Make sure your app is using RegionBootstrap as in the reference app as described in the "Starting an App in the Background" section [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)
3. When testing background detection, make sure you are out of region before starting the test.  To do this, bring your app to the foreground, and have your beacon(s) turned off for 30 seconds.  This will ensure you are out of region.  Always to this before starting a background detection test.
4. If you kill your app from the task switcher, wait 5 minutes to ensure it is restarted in the background before starting your testing.
5. Be realistic about how long it might take to detect a beacon in the background.  Read [here](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html) for more info.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your help. You really did a lot of the help for me. I appreciate with it. I run the app you give me: https://github.com/altbeacon/android-beacon-library-reference . I can catch the signal of Eddystone very well. I got the log of enter and exit signal.

Comment: But I cannot wake up my app except once. I added the code you refer to me:`beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));` and the part of: `Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
                null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);`Could you tell me what I should do still.  Thanks very much!!!!

Comment: The sample code will automatically launch the MainActivity the first time the beacon enters the region.  The next time it will send a local notification.  This is done for demonstration purposes.  If you want it to launch the activity each time, simply change this code: `if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {  Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity"); ... }` to instead be `if (true) {  Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity"); ... }`.  This will make it *ALWAYS* launch the activity on detection.

Comment: Hi David, I can launch the app if the app run in the background. However, it will not show the log of "did enter region " or run my service if I kill it by clean memory function in Android. Could you tell me whether the app will run automatically if the Android Beacon is not run in background or even never start after the system boot please. Thanks very much and with my best wish.

Comment: It is designed to do exactly that.  What is your phone model and OS version?

Comment: Hi David, I am so happy you can help me for these days. I studied several week in China with little info here. My phone is not included Google Service. I guess this is the reason I cannot wake my app automatically. I tested the app in Nexus 6p and it worked well, But in Chinese android mobile phone, nothing happened. However I still need your confirm that Eddystone need Google Service or some other support which is not in Chinese phone. Best regards. From Glen.

Comment: No, Google services are not required.  The issue may be with a specific vendor modification to the Android OS.  Huawei's Emui fork of Android, for example, aggressively kills apps that are not in the foreground.